# How can I select non null columns from a view of EAV tables

Tags: sql-server, view, eav

I have a VIEW that queries my E-A-V model which uses datatype tables to store the values. I have an entity that contains many attributes, each attribute can be a different datatype. The DataType tables are all identically structured except for storage type they have 4 columns, required, Min, Max and Value (of the respective datatype for the table).

I would like simply get something like

> MyAttributeName, Min, Max, Value, Required

I have tables like this..

- [Attribute:: Attribute_Id, Name] [Machine:: Machine_Id, Name]
- [Attribute_Val_Int :: Id, Attribute_Id, Machine_Id, Min, Max, Value,Required]
- [Attribute_Val_Dec :: Id, Attribute_Id, Machine_Id, Min,Max, Value, Required]
- [Attribute_Val_Dat :: Id, Attribute_Id,
  Machine_Id, Min, Max, Value, Required]

While I can get all of the Attribute Type Values (in this example I get 12 columns back - I want only the Attribute_Val that has non-null values. I would like the Column Names to then be aliased Min, Max, Val, Required

So instead of receiving this:

> MachineName, MyAttributeName, IntMin, IntMax, IntValue, IntRequired,
>   DecMin, DecMax, DecValue, DecRequired, DatMin, DatMax, DatValue,
>   DatRequired.

I want to get:

> [MachineName, MyAttributeName, Min, Max, Value, Required]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about

```
SELECT MachineName, 
       MyAttributeName, 
       COALESCE(IntMin, DecMin, DatMin) ValMin,
       COALESCE(IntMax, DecMax, DatMax) ValMax, 
       COALESCE(IntValue, DecValue, DatValue) ValValue,
       COALESCE(IntRequired, DecRequired, DatRequired) ValRerquired
```

But it seems you must to convert all separate values to the same datatype (string?) to avoid an error.

Comment: yes the string issue creates somewhat of a problem, but gives me an idea.  When comparing to determine if within the range a string of 10242018 and 11182020 has to be reconverted to date and I then need the datatype for the column. The Int and Decimal fields as decimal is easy enough because 1 and 1.0 is straight forward.So my options are to store the date as a non-date more like milliseconds value in which case it is numeric type. I can then convert string back to Decimal for comparing. I am going to mark this as answer because it gives me another idea to simplify storage.

Comment: Is there any way to know which column is the non-null and get datatype so as to create a temp table with that column and insert values ?

Comment: Maybe... but I don't know how to do it.